# How to save the content of a textarea into a html file in PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

so basically i have a textarea and a save as button using form method. When the user click the save as, a dialog will pop up and ask what the file name is and where to save it. Is this possible using php or javascript ?

Comment: Yes, but **be careful!** If you have PHP support, your user may enter PHP code in the textarea and save it as a PHP file. When he then navigates to that file in his browser, your server will execute his code. That's a huge security risk. You should store these files in a separate directory and make sure they are never executed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with php. just follow these steps

1->accept input from user (filename and text) 
2->sanitize inputs

then this snippet will work for u

```
<?php
$file = $_POST['filename']. ".txt"; // getting filename and storing to variable

$content = $_POST['text_from_user']; // getting file contents from textarea

// Write the contents to the file
file_put_contents($file, $content);
?>
```